# How to implement i18n in GWT application?

Tags: gwt, internationalization, gwt2, uibinder

I have a problem with internationalization. I'm trying to implement support two languages ​​in my GWT application. Unfortunately I never found a complete example how to do it with the help of UiBinder. That is what I did:

My module **I18nexample.gwt.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module rename-to='i18nexample'>
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.User" />
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.clean.Clean' />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales" />
<entry-point class='com.myexample.i18nexample.client.ExampleI18N' />
<servlet path="/start" class="com.myexample.i18nexample.server.StartServiceImpl" />
    <extend-property name="locale" values="en, fr" />
    <set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
</module>
```

My interface **Message.java**:

```
package com.myexample.i18nexample.client;

import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;

public interface Message extends Constants {

    String greeting();
}
```

The same package `com.myexample.i18nexample.client` has three properties file:

**Message.properties**:

```
greeting = hello
```

**Message_en.properties**:

```
greeting = hello
```

**Message_fr.properties**:

```
greeting = bonjour
```

My UiBinder file **Greeting.ui.xml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder 
    xmlns:ui="urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder"
    xmlns:g="urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui"
    ui:generateFormat="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.format.PropertiesFormat"
    ui:generateKeys="com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.keygen.MD5KeyGenerator"
    ui:generateLocales="default" >
    <ui:with type="com.myexample.i18nexample.client.Message" field="string" />
    <g:HTMLPanel>   
        <ui:msg key="greeting" description="greeting">Default greeting</ui:msg>     
    </g:HTMLPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

When the application starts, I always get the output in the browser:

```
Default greeting
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

I tried to run the application from different URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/i18nexample.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

http://127.0.0.1:8888/i18nexample.html?locale=en&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

http://127.0.0.1:8888/i18nexample.html?locale=fr&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

The result does not change. Although I expected in last case a message `bonjour`.

If for example I use a `g:Buttton` instead of the message `ui:msg`:

```
<g:HTMLPanel>   
     <g:Button text="{string.greeting}" />      
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

Then I get as a result of the button with text `"hello"`

And if I enter the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/i18nexample.html?locale=fr&gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

The text on the button changes to `"bonjour"`. Here everything works as expected. But why internationalization is not working in my first case?

And whether there is a difference between the following:

```
<ui:msg description="greeting">Default greeting</ui:msg>

<ui:msg description="greeting">hello</ui:msg>

<ui:msg description="greeting"></ui:msg>
```

Should there be different results in these cases? How to write properly?

Please explain to me the principles of internationalization in GWT and why my example does not work.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the files should be named `Message_fr.properties` (resp. `Message_en.properties`), not `Message.properties_fr` (resp. `Message.properties_en`).

Then `ui:msg` et al. in UiBinder will **generate** an interface (extending `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Messages`)), not use one that you defined. For that, you have to use `{string.greeting}` (where `string` is the `ui:field` you gave to your `ui:with`). The UiBinder generator will do a `GWT.create()` on the `type` class of your `ui:with`, which is what you'd have done in Java code:

```java
Message string = GWT.create(Message.class);
String localizedGreeting = string.greeting();
```

In the implicit Messages interface (generated by UiBinder), the various `ui:generateXxx` attributes on the `ui:UiBinder` will be transformed into annotations on the interface (properties of the [`@Generate`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizableResource.Generate.html) annotation, or the value of the [`@GenerateKeys`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizableResource.GenerateKeys.html) annotation).
Then, one method will be generated for each `ui:msg`, where the attributes generate equivalent annotations (`@Key`, `@Description`) and the content of the `ui:msg` element is the value of the `@DefaultMessage` annotation. When you have  or widgets inside the content, they'll be turned into arguments to the method and placeholders in the `@DefaultMessage` text (the values will be filled by UiBinder).

I'd suggest you make something working without UiBinder first, and understand *how* it works; then try the `ui:msg` in UiBinder, using `-gen` in DevMode or the compiler so you can see exactly what code does UiBinder generate (yes, it really only generates code that you could have written yourself by hand).

Also, you should add a `<set-property name="locale" value="en, fr" />` or you'll still have the `default` locale around, despite the `set-property-fallback` (it'd just never be used)).

Comment: Pardon me, `.properties` files of course is actually named correctly. It's just a typo. Thank you for your answer. But unfortunately it does not add clarity for me and my problem. Everything works properly without the using of UiBinder. But I want to understand how to internationalize an application properly exactly  with UiBinder.

Comment: Could you write exactly what I need to fix or provide a link to the full completed sample? I would be very grateful!

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinderI18n If you want to use `ui:msg` you have to provide the properties files in the same package, named the same as the UiBinder interface with a `ImplGenMessages` suffix. Alternatively, you can use `com/google/gwt/i18n/client/LocalizedResource_<locale>.properties` and/but then centralize all your messages. And again, use `-gen` and look at the generated code.

Comment: You can provide the properties in another package, but you'll have to write the interface yourself (not that much work normally), if you set your custom interface as base interface, e.g. `ui:baseMessagesInterface="com.company.i18n.CoreMessages"`